# How to reset imported file after every test in vitest?

Tags: typescript, mocking, vitest

I need to reset an imported file completely after every test.
From what I understand calling `vi.mock` should mock my imported file using it's original contents.
But it seems that any calls that should modify the file don't work.
My files:

```
src/
  lib/
    index.ts
    index.test.ts
```

```js
// index.js
const settings = { value: '' }

export function setValue(val) {
  settings.value = val;
}

export function getValue() {
  return settings.value;
}
```

```js
// index.test.js
import { setValue, getValue } from "./index.js";
import { afterEach, describe, expect, it, vi } from "vitest";

vi.mock("./index.js");

describe("setValue", () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        vi.clearAllMocks();
        vi.resetAllMocks();
    });
    it("test1", () => {
        setValue('en')
        expect(getValue()).toBe('en'); // i'm getting undefined
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`vi.resetModules()`](https://vitest.dev/api/vi#vi-resetmodules), e.g.:

```js
describe('setValue', () => {
  let setValue, getValue;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    vi.resetModules();
    ({ setValue, getValue }) = await import('./index.js');
  });

  it('test1', () => {
    expect(getValue()).toBe('');
    setValue('en');
    expect(getValue()).toBe('en');
  });

  it('test2', () => {
    expect(getValue()).toBe('');
    setValue('es');
    expect(getValue()).toBe('es');
  });
});
```

Note that:

> Top-level imports cannot be re-evaluated.

This is why `'index.js'` is imported using `await import(...)` instead of `import ... from ...` in the example above.